# How can I find where a Script project is referenced as a library

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries

I have a Google Apps Script project that is used as a library by other projects.

I have annotated, on a separate document, where this script is used, but I cannot find a way to double-check this list.

Is it possible to perform a search, using the project ID or other elements, returning all the other projects where my script is referenced as a library?

I tried using search in Drive, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to search for which projects use your library. At most your library could create a log of when it's called (but not who calls it), and those using the previous version wont pick that change so you cant even log those calls.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the answer